# Delphi and C/C++ DLL Struct vs.Record

Tags: c++, c, delphi, memory-management, dll

I previously asked a question about a delphi and a C/C++ DLL.

I have now another question about a record / struct.
The DLL should be able to dynamically CHANGE the VALUE of the pointer vars from the MainAPP.

My delphi MAINAPP has the following record:

```
type MyRec = record
 MyInteger    : Pointer;
 MyWideString : pwidechar;
 MyString     : pchar;
 MyBool       : Pointer
end;

type
 TMyFunc = function ( p  : pointer ): pointer; stdcall;

procedure test;
var
 MyFunction  : TMyFunc;
 TheRecord   : MyRec;
 AnInteger   : Integer;
 AWideString : WideString;
 AString     : String;
 ABool       : Bool;
begin
 AnInteger                := 1234;
 AWideString              := 'hello';
 AString                  := 'hello2';
 ABool                    := TRUE;
 TheRecord.MyInteger      := @AnInteger;
 TheRecord.MyWideString   := pwidechar(AWideString);
 TheRecord.AString        := pchar(AString);
 TheRecord.ABool          := @ABool;
 [...]
 @MyFunction := GetProcAddress...
 [...]
 MyFunction  (@TheRecord);  // now the DLL should be able to change the values dynamically.
 MessageBoxW (0, pwidechar(AWideString), '', 0); // Show the results how the DLL changed the String to...
end;
```

C/C++ Code (just example)

```
typedef struct _TestStruct{
void    *TheInteger;    // Pointer to Integer
wchar_t *TheWideString; // Pointer to WideString
char    *TheAnsiString; // Pointer to AnsiString  
bool    *TheBool        // Pointer to Bool
}TestStruct;

__declspec(dllexport) PVOID __stdcall MyExportedFunc (TestStruct *PTestStruct)
{
MessageBoxW(0 ,PTestStruct->TheWideString, L"Debug" , 0); // We read the value.
    PTestStruct->TheWideString = L"Let me change the value here.";
return 0;
}
```

For some reasons it crashes etc.
What do I do wrong?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Did you check that MyFunction reference <> nil  before calling?

Comment: The function gets called just fine and returns <> NIL.

Comment: it crashes when I try to change the value of the pwidechar

Comment: The MyRec record declaration in Delphi has a different field order that the one in the _TestStruct C struct

Comment: sorry about that. That's not the problem. I edited it.

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss: removed my previous answer - you said that C++ function call succeeds then it fails somewhere after the call. Could you point to the line of the code that fails?

Comment: PTestStruct->TheWideString = L"Let me change the value here."; that's where it crashes.

Comment: Be polite to potential answerers - include error message you receive when your app crashes.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not a C/C++ coder. A friend just told me that it doesn't work. He said both the mainapp and the DLL crash.

Comment: Ask your friend for the error message/exception type s/he is getting

Comment: You should read the answer that you accepted in your previous question and follow the advice given. This question is in fact an exact duplicate of your previous question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mismanaging the string fields.  `PWideChar` and `PChar` **are not** the same thing as "pointer to WideString" and "pointer to AnsiString".  Delphi has `PWideString` (`WideString*`) and `PAnsiString` (`AnsiString*`) types for that purpose instead.  You should also use Delphi's `PInteger` (`int*`) and `PBoolean` (`bool*`) types instead of `Pointer` (`void*`).  Delphi and C++ are both type-safe languages.  Stay away from untyped pointers when possible, your code will be better for it.

```
type
  PMyRec = ^MyRec;
  MyRec = record
    MyInteger    : PInteger;
    MyWideString : PWideString;
    MyAnsiString : PAnsiString;
    MyBool       : PBoolean;
  end;

  TMyFunc = function ( p  : PMyRec ): Integer; stdcall;

procedure test;
var
  MyFunction  : TMyFunc;
  TheRecord   : MyRec;
  AnInteger   : Integer;
  AWideString : WideString;
  AAnsiString : AnsiString;
  ABool       : Bool;
begin
 AnInteger                := 1234;
 AWideString              := 'hello';
 AAnsiString              := 'hello2';
 ABool                    := TRUE;
 TheRecord.MyInteger      := @AnInteger;
 TheRecord.MyWideString   := @AWideString;
 TheRecord.MyAnsiString   := @AAnsiString;
 TheRecord.MyBool         := @ABool;
 [...]
 @MyFunction := GetProcAddress...
 [...]
 MyFunction  (@TheRecord); 
 MessageBoxW (0, PWideChar(AWideString), '', 0);
end;
```

.

```
typedef struct _MyRec
{
    int        *MyInteger;    // Pointer to Integer
    WideString *MyWideString; // Pointer to WideString
    AnsiString *MyAnsiString; // Pointer to AnsiString  
    bool       *MyBool;       // Pointer to Bool
} MyRec, *PMyRec;

__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall MyExportedFunc (PMyRec PRec)
{
    MessageBoxW(NULL, PRec->MyWideString->c_bstr(), L"Debug" , 0);
    *(PRec->MyWideString) = L"Let me change the value here.";
    return 0;
}
```

With that said, it can be very dangerous to manipulate `AnsiString` (and `UnicodeString`) values across a DLL boundary like this, especially if the EXE and DLL are written in different versions of Delphi/C++Builder due to RTL differences, memory manager differences, payload layout differences, etc.  `WideString` is OK to pass around, though, because it's memory and layout are controlled by the OS, not the RTL.

Comment: Can't try this right now. But why should I stay away from untyped pointers? Also does C/C++ have WideString?

Comment: Because the compiler cannot validate your code for safety when you use untyped pointers. You throw away all the information the compiler gathers for you.  And yes, C++Builder has a `WideString` class that is binary compatible with Delphi's `WideString` type, same with `AnsiString` and `UnicodeString`. But if you need to support other C++ compilers, then you can't use `AnsiString` and `UnicodeString` in this type of code at all, you need to use a different design.

Comment: WideString maps to BSTR in C++

Answer (score 2):

This probably isn't the cause of the crash at the point where the C++ code assigns to the `TheWideString` pointer, but I do see a problem of expectations...

I notice that you're putting the address of the string data that the Delphi `AWideString` variable points to into the `MyWideString` field of the record.  You pass the record to the C++ function, which assigns a new pointer value to the `TheWideString/MyWideString` field of the record. When execution returns to the Delphi code, you output the contents of the `AWideString` variable.

Your comments indicate that you expect the contents of the AWideString variable to be changed by the C++ function, but that's not what will happen.

The C++ function changes the field in the structure. It does nothing to the memory location that the field previously pointed to.  The data that AWideString points to will not be affected by the C++ function.

If the C++ code copied data into the address contained in the field, then it would overwrite the string data that `AWideString` points to. Since `AWideString` is a Delphi managed string, and the C++ function would be copying more data to that string memory area than the original string had allocated space for, copying data in the C++ function would write past the end of the Delphi allocated string buffer and probably corrupt the Delphi heap. A crash may occur some time later. So it's a good that you're only assigning the pointer to the field, not copying the data! ;>

To see what the C++ function changed, your Delphi code should output the contents of the `MyWideString` field of the record after the call to the C++ function.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronize fields order in the structures. You can break memory heap using wrong pointers. Also, check alignment both in Delphi and C++.

Comment: the structure works just fine. I can read all the values. I just can't change them.

Comment: Brr. I've deleted my previous posts - I am a bit stupid by mornings)
Try to use SysAllocString when you are passes strings over different dlls. Comething like this:
PTestStruct->TheWideString = SysAllocString(L"Let me change the value here.");