# How to pass complex object from C# to Delphi?

Tags: c#, xml, database, delphi

I am creating a c# library for a delphi executable to use.

Currently I can easily pass primitive data types back to Delphi

```
DllExport("GetUserCreationDate", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static string getString(string stringGiven)
```

However, I now want to pass a List of more complex objects, which have 4 fields.

The List of objects are like this:

```
 public class Model{
 public string header;
public string body;
public bool istrue;

}
```

The options I believe are available are:

1) Replicate the object within a database table and write to this table within the C# dll and then retrieve the rows from Delphi executable

2) Store the information within an XML file and parse the XML from Delphi executable

However, both are these are suitable for the current situation. Is it possible to:

3) Pass the complex object directly back to Delphi executable

Which method do you think is best and are there any better ways of achieving this?

Comment: Why not pass a struct

Comment: how would one do that?

Comment: this answer probably answers that question http://stackoverflow.com/a/11733168/4780

Comment: Do some research, this topic has been well covered

Comment: 4pm on a Friday, lots of reading to be done. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Bouncing through a database or a file seem silly if it's within the same application.  Passing a JSON string may be an alternative, depending on how complex the object is.  A struct is not good with reference types or nested objects, etc.

Comment: Yes I was considering possibly using JSON, they are just basic data types though so would a struct be ok for that? (3x strings, 1x bool)

Comment: Be more specific about *complex object*. What specific data types are you attempting to pass back and forth? Any answer would depend on that information (and it would change your question from a *vote to close as unclear* or *vote to close as too broad* to something that might warrant leaving open).

Comment: I've added the change - its basically a list of an object which contains 4 primitive data types

Comment: @markthewizard1234 that's not a complex object at all.  Wrap three setters and be done with it.

Comment: JSON and pass a string. It's 2016 bro.

Comment: If you want to pass a living object with dynamic behaviour - then create OLE/COM object in C# - Delphi have native support for COM objects. If you want to pass a complex but static data - then pass JSON or XML text.

Comment: Serializing to Json seems heavy to me

Comment: @DavidHeffernan depends upon how often it would be done.